# Using Qt Designer files in python script

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer, pyuic

I need to open a dialog from *login.py*, then if successful, the dialog will close and open a main-window from *home.py*. I need to do this with a file created by Qt Designer with pyuic4. In summary, I need to call *login.py* and *home.py* though *main.py*.

Code of *main.py*:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore 
import sqlite3, time
from login import Ui_Dialog
from home import Ui_MainWindow

# Here I need to know how to call login.py, and
# after logged in, how to change to home.py

class RunApp():
    pass        

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = RunApp()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Code of *login.py*:

```
class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(194, 156)
```

Code of *home.py*:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(635, 396)
        MainWindow.setAutoFillBackground(False)
```

**Update:**
**Thanks my friends ;) Worked for me with this code:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from login import Ui_Dialog
from home import Ui_MainWindow
import sqlite3, time, sys, os

class MyLogin(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.openHome)
    def openHome(self):
        ui2 = MyHome()
        ui2.show()
        ui2.exec_()


class MyHome(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui2 = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui2.setupUi(self)

if __name__=='__main__':
    root = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app = MyLogin()
    app.show()
    root.exec_()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a class that derives from `QWidget`, and in its `__init__` instantiate the ui class,  then call `setupUi(self)` on it.

```
class RunApp():
    pass  

class MyDialog(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

# do same for Ui_MainWindow via class MyMainWindow(QWidget)
...
```

This is explained in

- [Qt docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-a-ui-file.html) (you'll have to do the usual C++ -> Python translation)
- [Qt examples for Designer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-designer.html) (you'll have to do the usual C++ -> Python translation)
- [PyQt examples](https://github.com/pyqt/examples)

Answer (score 0):

For login page of PyQt based application. i would suggest use [QstackedWidget](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qstackedwidget.html)

> Page1 in stackedwidget for login page
>
> Page2 in stackwidget for home screen

all you need is a simple login function that will varify the user name and password and allow user to move to home screen.

you can change the current index to open home screen.

```
  self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)
```